# What is effect to me if my question or answers receive too much downvote?

Tags: discussion, support

What is effect to me if my question or answers receive too much downvote?

Comment: Suggested rephrasing: "What effect can it have on my account if my questions or answers receive too many downvotes?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect on you is that you lose "reputation".

Each time someone downvotes a question or an answer that you have written, you get -2 "reputation", but it will never drop below 1.  This is explained [in the Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

A question with many downvotes is less likely to be seen by other users, so another effect is that it becomes less likely to attract an answer.

As pointed out in comments below, receiving consistent downvotes may get you temporarily blocked from asking further questions, and eventually even banned from asking *any* questions.

Comment: There's also the risk of https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited but I can't put my finger on the details.

Comment: [downvotes and bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227291/307535) -- one breadcrumb on meta